# Cannot Figure Out Loop. Hope for Assistance

Tags: java, exception, loops, bluej

I'm fairly new to `Java` and I'm using `BlueJ`. To make my program work, I need to:

```
    //  Insert code here to perform a sequence of
    //  interactive transactions with the user.
    //  The user enters an item number and the program
    //  either displays the item or prints an error message
    //  if the item is not found.  The program terminates
    //  when the user enters zero as the item number.
```

I can't seem to get the program to work, unfortunately. Hopefully someone can assist me.

This is the `class Program2` that needs the loop:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        Catalog store = new Catalog(3);
        int itemnum = 0;
        Item item;

        try {
            store.insert
              (new Music(1111, "Gold", 12.00, "Abba"));
            store.insert
              (new Movie(2222, "Mamma Mia", 16.00, "Meryl Streep"));
            store.insert
              (new Book(3333, "DaVinci Code", 8.00, "Dan Brown"));
              store.insert
            (new Music(4444, "Legend", 15.00, "Bob Marley"));
            } catch (CatalogFull exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }


        //  Insert code here to perform a sequence of
        //  interactive transactions with the user.
        //  The user enters an item number and the program
        //  either displays the item or prints an error message
        //  if the item is not found.  The program terminates
        //  when the user enters zero as the item number.

        itemnum = kbd.nextInt();
        while (itemnum == 0) {
            item = store.find(itemnum);
            if (item != null) {
                System.out.print(itemnum);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s was not found.%n", item);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Player (0 to exit)? ");
            itemnum = kbd.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment the current error is in the loop on "(itemnum)" saying:

```
unreported exception ItemNotFound; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

That being said, I suspect that's not the only issue, and I'm not doing this part of the program correctly. Hopefully someone can help me out. Thank you in advance.

Here are some other classes that may or may not be useful:

This is `class ItemNotFound`:

```
// This exception is thrown when searching for an item
// that is not in the catalog.
public class ItemNotFound extends Exception {
    public ItemNotFound(int id) {
        super(String.format("Item %d was not found.", id));
    }
}
```

This is `class CatalogFull`

```
// This exception is thrown when trying to insert an item
// when the catalog is full.
public class CatalogFull extends Exception {
    public CatalogFull() {
        super("The catalog is full.");
    }
}
```

This is `class Catalog`:

```
public class Catalog {
    private Item[] list;
    private int size;

    // Construct an empty catalog with the specified capacity.
    public Catalog(int max) {
        list = new Item[max];
        size = 0;
    }

    // Insert a new item into the catalog.
    // Throw a CatalogFull exception if the catalog is full.
    public void insert(Item obj) throws CatalogFull {
        if (list.length == size) {
            throw new CatalogFull();
        }
        list[size] = obj;
        ++size;
    }

    // Search the catalog for the item whose item number
    // is the parameter id.  Return the matching object 
    // if the search succeeds.  Throw an ItemNotFound
    // exception if the search fails.
    public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos){
            if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber()){
                return list[pos];
            }
        }
        throw new ItemNotFound(id);
        }
}
```

This is `class Item`:

```
public class Item {
    private int itemnum;
    private String title;
    private double price;

    // Construct a new item object.
    public Item(int id, String t, double p) {
        itemnum = id;
        title = t;
        price = p;
    }

    // Return the item number of this item.
    public int getItemNumber() {
        return itemnum;
    }

    // Return the item type. This is overridden in subclasses.
    public String getItemType() {
        return "Item";
    }

    // Return a printable String represenation of this item.
    public String toString() {
        String line1, line2, line3, line4, out;
        String itemtype = this.getItemType();
        line1 = String.format("Item number: %d%n", itemnum);
        line2 = String.format("Item type:   %s%n", itemtype);
        line3 = String.format("Item title:  %s%n", title);
        line4 = String.format("Item price:  %.2f%n", price);
        out = line1 + line2 + line3 + line4;
        return out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item = store.find(itemnum); //here you are finding the item
```

Your find(int id) method thows the  ItemNotFound  exception. We need to handle the ItemNotFound exception here.

```
    itemnum = kbd.nextInt();
    while (itemnum == 0) {
      try{
        item = store.find(itemnum);

          if (item != null) {
             System.out.print(itemnum);
          } 
        } catch (ItemNotFound e){
            System.out.println(" Item  was not found with id :"+ itemnum);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Player (0 to exit)? ");
        itemnum = kbd.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined the method `find()` like so that it's throwing `ItemNotFound` exception when no Item found.

```
   public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
```

Compiler is telling that the method `find()`  might throw the `Exception`,Please take necessary steps.

So you need to put this line   `item = store.find(itemnum);`  in `try catch block`, and handle it.

So,

```
try{

     item = store.find(itemnum);

} catch (ItemNotFound e){

//handle it

}
```